# replacement for write/readXXXLE in netty 5

Tags: java, netty, endianness

I heard that write/readXXXLE was deleted from netty 5. Is there a replacement for writeXXXLE or readXXXLE in netty 5? reverseBytes doesn't seem to work on float/double and unsigned.